# How to parse string as JSON object javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following code from my php script.

```
var str = "[{id : 'Gadji Tallo', poste : 'attaquants', taille : '1.85m', poids :'77kg', age :'20'},{id:'Mbaye Diagne', poste :'attaquants', taille : '', poids :'', age :'22'},{id:'Sigamary Diarra', poste :'attaquants', taille : '1.76m', poids :'74kg', age :'29'}]";
var result = JSON.parse(str)
```

what I want is to parse it as JSON to loop through it.
When I run the following code I got this error in my chrome console:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i**

Any clue / help is welcom.
Thanks

Comment: That is not valid JSON. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: use JSON.prase() to parse JSON and eval() to parse JS: eval("0||"+str)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely parsing a JSON string with unquoted keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210160/safely-parsing-a-json-string-with-unquoted-keys)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't JSON but it's almost a literal JavaScript Object and you don't seem to really need JSON.

As you generate this in PHP, simply don't put the quotes and no parsing is needed :

```
var result = [{id : 'Gadji Tallo', poste : 'attaquants', taille : '1.85m', poids :'77kg', age :'20'},{id:'Mbaye Diagne', poste :'attaquants', taille : '', poids :'', age :'22'},{id:'Sigamary Diarra', poste :'attaquants', taille : '1.76m', poids :'74kg', age :'29'}];
```

Comment: I've modified my php script to generate a valid JSON such as [{"id":"Gadji Tallo","poste":"attaquants","taille":"1.85m","poids":"77kg","age":"20"}] but still get an error when I want to parse it.

Comment: Why do you want to parse it ? If you generate some literal it's directly usable.

Comment: what I want to do is to loop through each object. Wehn I execute console.log (msg) when msg equals the string above  I got the number of characters when I wan the number of object whithin my array. $`.ajax({....}).done(function( msg ) {
console.log(msg ); =>[{"id":"Gadji Tallo","poste":"attaquants","taille":"1.85m","poids":"77kg
","age":"20"},{"id":"Mbaye Diagne","poste":"attaquants","taille":"","poids":"","age":"22"}]
console.log (msg.length); => 179`

Comment: You use ajax to get the string ? This looks like a totally different question from your initial one...

Comment: yes I use ajax to retrieve the string by calling a php script

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40519/discussion-between-user1128939-and-dystroy)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to also put quotes around the names, for example:

```
var str = '[{"id" : "Gadji Tallo", "poste" : "attaquants", "taille" : "1.85m", "poids":"77kg", "age" :"20"}]';
```

when parsing JSON from a string.

If you are printing JSON from PHP why don't just keep the array in PHP and then print

```
print "var obj = " . json_encode($array);
```

Comment: it's already done `[{"id":"Gadji Tallo","poste":"attaquants","taille":"1.85m","poids":"77kg ","age":"20"},{"id":"Mbaye Diagne","poste":"attaquants","taille":"","poids":"","age":"22"}]`

Comment: same result with json_encode when I run a lenght on the result

Comment: Why did you "run a length on the result"? It's a property, not a method.

Comment: because I want to loop through the result (coming from an ajax call) which is a string representing an array of object. So I run length property to check if my result  is well evaluated (by giving number of object in the array and not the char length. What I want is to retrieve the value of each property in the object.