# Jquery Mapael : How to dynamically construct the list of areas?

Tags: jquery, mapael

currently, when you initialize the areas, you have to write something like :

```
areas : { 'id1' : { ... },}
```

My problem is that I would like to initialize it with a variable, but if I write :

```
var myareas={}
var myareas['id1']={...}

areas: myareas
```

This doesn't work as it generates :

```
areas : { id1 : {...}}
```

stripping the quotes around id1

Any idea?

Comment: looks like a JavaScript vs. JSON syntax issue, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210160/safely-parsing-a-json-string-with-unquoted-keys)

Comment: @dlatikay : thank you, but I have solved the problem

Comment: I guess that after many tries, I got confused : it works perfectly