# Convert Array in the string type to regular array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string variable in javascript called temp:

`temp = "[{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 2, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 3}]"`

How I can convert the string temp to array?

To be like:

`temp = [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 2, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 3}]`

Comment: Why don't you fix whatever produces the first `temp` to instead produce valid JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string were in valid JSON format you could use `JSON.parse()`. But it's not, so the only general solution (short of writing your own parser) is `eval()`.

```js
var temp = "[{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 2, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 3}]"
var result = eval(temp);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be extracted as `array` using [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) javascript function.

```js
const input = "[{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 2, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 3}]";
const output = eval(input);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = ['foo,', 'bar', 'red,', 'car']
console.log(arr.join(' '))//"foo, bar red, car"
```

You can simply use the **join()** function to convert the array into string

Answer (score -1):

`JSON.parse` should work, if I understand the question correctly

You can use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210160/safely-parsing-a-json-string-with-unquoted-keys) for fixing the JSON before parsing it

Comment: JSON requires the property names to be in double quotes.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON, so parsing will fail.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice the names not being quoted